# XPages for iPhone6: Which controls or framework do you use?

Tags: xpages

Just got a request for a fresh XPages project where an existing traditional Domino Web application should be modernized and mobilified (iPhone 6 being the target).

I'm comfortable with Boostrap, especially Mark Leuksinks add-on, and that is my first gut feeling.

On the other hand I'm aware of specific Mobile Controls, both from IBM and from Teamstudio, and was wondering if there is a 'best way' you would recommend.

I can pretty much control everything on the server. I'm aiming for quickest effect for minimum effort.

Comment: "It depends" is the easy answer :-) Want offline with XPages and don't mind extra license costs? Unplugged might work well for you. Still want offline and have time to learn Angular? Check out Ionic. If offline isn't needed it gets a lot easier and Bootstrap (or the XControls) will work. If you want to only do Bootstrap and have something that looks like iOS, check out Bootcards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TeamStudio tools are good if you want offline or do other development that does offline (XControls can also be used online, so could give consistent look and feel and development experience).

XPages Mobile Controls require a single XPage in order to get transitions. So if it's a large application, that can make the XPage quite cumbersome. You need to become comfortable with the settings on each mobile page, to know when to refresh and when not to.

If you're familiar with Bootstrap and can "encourage" the end users towards your preference, then as a developer, that would make sense to me (leveraging existing skills means quicker development).

Answer (score 0):

If you're comfortable with Bootstrap and responsive design, we'd certainly encourage going down that route. I take it you are aware that Bootstrap is now part of the XPages Extension Library on OpenNTF ? It was first released there in Nov 2014 and has been continuously updated since. And it will migrate to the core XPages runtime as part of the next GA release

Answer (score 0):

I would use the DAS components and let Domino read/write JSON and implement the frontend using the IONIC framework. It uses AngularJS as JS framework, is conceptually not that different from Bootstrap l, but has all the hooks (using Cordova) to use native phone features.

Comment: That looks like an interesting approach. It seems for mobile only though - could I have a coexistence of a traditional Domino Web Application and the ionic 'application' or would it have to be both in Ionic? And if coexistence, how would one branch one user to the mobile version, and another to the browser version?

Comment: Api can serve any type of client

Comment: I've looked into DAS - According to this https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Authenticating_Domino_REST_Service_Requests I should use basic authentication; isn't that considered unsafe?

Comment: Not for https. And HTTP is not save for ANY authentication

Comment: I'd like to mark both Paul's and your answer as the correct one, but this is a sort of 'opinion question' anyway. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Mark Paul's. Good with me